# Convert varchar containing various formats to DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I have a record_created column of type varchar containing multiple values formatted in two different ways throughout.

- 2017-04-17 16:55:53.3840460
- Sep 18 2015 11:25PM

How can I convert this column into a DATETIME to be compared to GETDATE?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. And GETDATE is a product specific function.)

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server` etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GETDATE()` is `SQL Server` specific if so, then you can use [try_convert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
select cast(try_convert(datetime2, col) as datetime)
from table t
where try_convert(datetime2, col) is not null;
```

However, if the string date is exactly the same format which you have provide then you can simply do casting :

```
select cast(cast(col as datetime2) as datetime)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, then you may be able to use the `CONVERT` function here:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(datetime, LEFT('2017-04-17 16:55:53.3840460', 23), 121) AS date1,
    CONVERT(datetime, 'Sep 18 2015 11:25PM', 100) AS date2;
```

Your first type of timestamp seems to work with mask 121, and the second one works with mask 100.  The demo link below shows that the conversions are working.

### Demo